# Need advice for decryption

Tags: java, encryption

I'm currently working on my final project, so far I have a signup page, that stores your Username, email and password.
For the password, it encrypts using a SHA algorithm, but I found out that the SHA digest the password, thus making it undecryptable.
I need your help so that I can find some sort of encryption-decryption code.
Here is the code I have:

```
 try {
        PrintWriter arq = new PrintWriter(jTextField1.getText()+".txt");
        arq.println("Username: " + jTextField1.getText());
        arq.println("Email: " + jTextField2.getText());




        String algorithm = "SHA";

        byte[] plainText = jPasswordField1.getText().getBytes();

    MessageDigest md = null;

    try {       
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }

    md.reset();     
    md.update(plainText);
    byte[] encodedPassword = md.digest();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < encodedPassword.length; i++) {
        if ((encodedPassword[i] & 0xff) < 0x10) {
            sb.append("0");
        }

        sb.append(Long.toString(encodedPassword[i] & 0xff, 16));
    }

        arq.println("Password: " + sb.toString());

        arq.close();
        if(!jTextField2.getText().equals(jTextField3.getText()) 
   ||!jPasswordField1.getText().equals(jPasswordField2.getText())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Either your email or 
   password are not corresponding. Please fix the issue.");
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account created!");
        }

    } catch (HeadlessException | FileNotFoundException erro) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error creating Account. Please 
   try again.");
    }
```

Fyi, this code is imbued onto a button from a JForm.
Thank you in advance for any help you may give.

Comment: It would help if you added the relevant programming language tag (Java?).

Comment: Sorry I forgot, yea the language used is Java.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gains admin access he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `password_hash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: This is just for a final project. It wont make to the market, at least in this stage. This is only a simple/intermediate program so that it asures I have a good grade.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

jBcrypt is another option if you are looking for encryption and decryption in Java.It is a password hashing function based on the Blowfish cipher. Following is a sample code to encrypt and decrypt password using jBcrypt.
**Encryption:**

```
public String hashPassword(String plainTextPassword){
        return BCrypt.hashpw(plainTextPassword, BCrypt.gensalt());
}
```

**Check for Password Match**

```
public boolean checkPass(String plainPassword, String hashedPassword) {
        if (BCrypt.checkpw(plainPassword, hashedPassword))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

Reference:
[Password Encryption using jBcypt](http://www.devglan.com/spring-mvc/storing-hashed-password-database-java)

Comment: There is no encryption or decryption taking place here.  Please learn the difference between encryption and hashing and edit your answer.